# INDIRECT function in Array Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Why does `INDIRECT(“65”)` work at the end of the first array, but it does not work at the end the second array?

```
=CORREL(E12:INDIRECT("65"),SPX!E12:INDIRECT("E65"))
```

Comment: Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to return the start and end boundaries of the cell range.

Comment: What are you expecting `INDIRECT("65")` to return? I get nothing but `#REF!` as is normal behavior with a malformed cell/range reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but instead of #VALUE it now returns #REF

Comment: Are you planning to post a link to the other site where you've raised this query and/or respond to answers posted there?

Answer (score 0):

The second indirect needs sheet reference :

`=CORREL(E12:INDIRECT("E65"),SPX!E12:INDIRECT("SPX!E65"))`